# Is there a way of adding more device frames within android studio for taking screenshots within logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently trying to take screenshots of my application through Logcat and apply them to a device frame but my only options are generic phone/tablet? - This is when connecting a Samsung galaxy s10E

When using a google pixel I am able to achieve a few more options such as pixel, pixel 2, nexus etc...

Is there any way to access Samsung galaxy frames or more up to date phone frames for use within logCat?

I have previously tried creating a custom ADV device and applying a samsung frame there and that somewhat works for an emulator but within logcat it still will only show the generic frames.

Any help / would be much appreciated

Thanks :)